# Problem with my dockerfile: ./bin/rails assets:precompile" did not complete successfully

Tags: ruby, docker, esbuild

When building my dockerfile I have the following error:

failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

It seems like I need to install yarn to precompile the assets on my rails project but I don't know how to do it.

Here is my dockerfile

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1

# Make sure RUBY_VERSION matches the Ruby version in .ruby-version and Gemfile
ARG RUBY_VERSION=3.2.2
FROM registry.docker.com/library/ruby:$RUBY_VERSION-slim as base

# Rails app lives here
WORKDIR /rails

# Set production environment
ENV RAILS_ENV="production" \
    BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT="1" \
    BUNDLE_PATH="/usr/local/bundle" \
    BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development"

# Throw-away build stage to reduce size of final image
FROM base as build

# Install packages needed to build gems
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential git yarn nodejs libpq-dev libvips pkg-config

# Install application gems
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install && \
    rm -rf ~/.bundle/ "${BUNDLE_PATH}"/ruby/*/cache "${BUNDLE_PATH}"/ruby/*/bundler/gems/*/.git && \
    bundle exec bootsnap precompile --gemfile


# Copy application code
COPY . .

# Precompile bootsnap code for faster boot times
RUN bundle exec bootsnap precompile app/ lib/

# Precompiling assets for production without requiring secret RAILS_MASTER_KEY
RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 ./bin/rails assets:precompile

# Final stage for app image
FROM base

# Install packages needed for deployment
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y curl libvips postgresql-client && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives

# Copy built artifacts: gems, application
COPY --from=build /usr/local/bundle /usr/local/bundle
COPY --from=build /rails /rails

# Run and own only the runtime files as a non-root user for security
RUN useradd rails --create-home --shell /bin/bash && \
    chown -R rails:rails db log storage tmp
USER rails:rails

# Entrypoint prepares the database.
ENTRYPOINT ["/rails/bin/docker-entrypoint"]

# Start the server by default, this can be overwritten at runtime
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["./bin/rails", "server"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-generate the dockerfile by using `bin/rails generate dockerfile` and it worked in the end.

Comment: What version of rails are you using? I can't seem to find this `generate dockerfile` anywhere. Is this like a separate gem maybe?